# How to concatenate a list with a nested list?

Tags: python

I have two lists:

The first one is a regular list which contains links of Sitemaps:

```
ur = ['https://www.hi.de/hu/sitemap.xml', 
      'https://www.hi.de/ma/sitemap.xml', 
      'https://www.hi.de/au/sitemap.xml', 
      ]
```

The second list is nested and contains links which were indexed on the sitemaps and a date for every link:

```
wh = [['No-Date', 'https://www.hi.de/hu/artikel/xxx', ''],        
      ['2019-11-13', 'https://www.hi.de/ma/artikel/xxx'], 
      ['2019-11-12', 'https://www.hi.de/ma/artikel/xxx'], 
      ['2019-11-11', 'https://www.hi.de/au/artikel/xxx']]
```

Now I want to merge the list with the nedted list based on the sitmap they came from like this:

```
ui = [['https://www.hi.de/hu/sitemap.xml', 'No-Date', 'https://www.hi.de/hu/artikel/xxx', ''],        
      ['https://www.hi.de/ma/sitemap.xml' '2019-11-13', 'https://www.hi.de/ma/artikel/xxx'], 
      ['https://www.hi.de/ma/sitemap.xml', '2019-11-12', 'https://www.hi.de/ma/artikel/xxx'], 
      ['https://www.hi.de/au/sitemap.xml', '2019-11-11', 'https://www.hi.de/au/artikel/xxx']]
```

But with my code:

```
ui = [[(url2, x) for url2 in ur for x in y if url2.rsplit('/', 1)[0] in x] for y in wh]
```

The date in every sublist gets deleted and additionally the entries are stored in a tuple like this:

```
...
[[('https://www.hi.de/hu/sitemap.xml', 'https://www.hi.de/hu/artikel/xxx', '')],
...
```

How can I change the code to get the desired result in the variable ui?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension that checks for the matching sitemap between two lists to get your desired result:

```
ur = ['https://www.hi.de/hu/sitemap.xml', 
      'https://www.hi.de/ma/sitemap.xml', 
      'https://www.hi.de/au/sitemap.xml', 
      ]

wh = [['No-Date', 'https://www.hi.de/hu/artikel/xxx', ''],        
      ['2019-11-13', 'https://www.hi.de/ma/artikel/xxx'], 
      ['2019-11-12', 'https://www.hi.de/ma/artikel/xxx'], 
      ['2019-11-11', 'https://www.hi.de/au/artikel/xxx']]

print([[[u] + x] for x in wh for u in ur if x[1].split('/')[3] == u.split('/')[3]])
```

which outputs:

```
[['https://www.hi.de/hu/sitemap.xml', 'No-Date', 'https://www.hi.de/hu/artikel/xxx', ''],
 ['https://www.hi.de/ma/sitemap.xml' '2019-11-13', 'https://www.hi.de/ma/artikel/xxx'],
 ['https://www.hi.de/ma/sitemap.xml', '2019-11-12', 'https://www.hi.de/ma/artikel/xxx'],
 ['https://www.hi.de/au/sitemap.xml', '2019-11-11', 'https://www.hi.de/au/artikel/xxx']]
```

Comment: Hi @Austin great solution! However it does not work if my list of sitemaps and urls is longer.

Comment: @gython, I assume sitemap always is at 3rd split of `/`. Please give an example of wrong case.

Comment: Hi @Austin, for example I am using a list with 11 sitemaps and a nested list with several thousand links. When I use your code for this case I am gettting the error: ```IndexError: list index out of range```. You are right, sitemap is always at 3rd split of /, but my problem is that my lists have more entries. Can you help me out?

Comment: Can you make sure `wh` is a list with each list in it has 2 elements and the second element of each list has a 3rd split, and same for `ur` list (has a 3rd split)? It seems either of the above cases is not true.

Comment: For easy debugging, convert this list comprehension to normal for loops and print element from `wh` and `ur` inside. Somewhere inside you will get `IndexError`; the element after just printed is the culprit.

Comment: Hi @Austin i just checked everything and it seems like there are links which have one slash less(in ```ur``` and ```wh```). Example: ```https://www.hi.de/fo/xxx``` What can I do here?

Comment: ```https://www.hi.de/fo/xxx``` is fine. Element at `[3]` here is `fo`; Hence no issue with this.

Comment: Hi @Austin I found the error, one sitemap is like this: ```https://www.te.de/sitemap.xml```

Comment: @gython, No that too is not the failure case. You have `sitemap.xml` at index 3.

Comment: You may have something like `https://www.something.de` or something. I guess you got the idea here.

Comment: But this sitemap link has another structure than the others? I thought this caused the error.

Comment: Hint: Look for urls where count of `/` is 3 or less.

Answer (score 4):

You can transform `ur` to a dictionary for easier lookup:

```
import re
ur = ['https://www.hi.de/hu/sitemap.xml', 'https://www.hi.de/ma/sitemap.xml', 'https://www.hi.de/au/sitemap.xml']
data = [['No-Date', 'https://www.hi.de/hu/artikel/xxx'], ['2019-11-13', 'https://www.hi.de/ma/artikel/xxx'], ['2019-11-12', 'https://www.hi.de/ma/artikel/xxx'], ['2019-11-11', 'https://www.hi.de/au/artikel/xxx']]
d = dict((re.split('/(?=sitemap\.)', i)[0], i) for i in ur)
result = [[d[re.split('/(?=\w{3,}/)', b)[0]], a, b] for a, b in data]
```

Output:

```
[['https://www.hi.de/hu/sitemap.xml', 'No-Date', 'https://www.hi.de/hu/artikel/xxx'], 
['https://www.hi.de/ma/sitemap.xml', '2019-11-13', 'https://www.hi.de/ma/artikel/xxx'], 
['https://www.hi.de/ma/sitemap.xml', '2019-11-12', 'https://www.hi.de/ma/artikel/xxx'], 
['https://www.hi.de/au/sitemap.xml', '2019-11-11', 'https://www.hi.de/au/artikel/xxx']]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could combine elements of your list with double `for` loop, unpack values of second list using [`*`-operator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists), and save them all using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
ui = [
    [i, *j] 
    for i in ur for j in wh 
    if i.split('/')[3] == j[1].split('/')[3]
]

print(ui)
```

**Output:**

```
[
    ['https://www.hi.de/hu/sitemap.xml', 'No-Date', 'https://www.hi.de/hu/artikel/xxx', ''],
    ['https://www.hi.de/ma/sitemap.xml', '2019-11-13', 'https://www.hi.de/ma/artikel/xxx'],
    ['https://www.hi.de/ma/sitemap.xml', '2019-11-12', 'https://www.hi.de/ma/artikel/xxx'],
    ['https://www.hi.de/au/sitemap.xml', '2019-11-11', 'https://www.hi.de/au/artikel/xxx']
]
```

Comment: What happened to this row  `['2019-11-11', 'https://www.hi.de/au/artikel/xxx']`? I think OP wants a lookup to sitemap, not just merge the lists.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a aimple `list` comprehension like,

```
>>> ur
['https://www.hi.de/hu/sitemap.xml', 'https://www.hi.de/ma/sitemap.xml', 'https://www.hi.de/au/sitemap.xml']
>>> wh
[['No-Date', 'https://www.hi.de/hu/artikel/xxx', ''], ['2019-11-13', 'https://www.hi.de/ma/artikel/xxx'], ['2019-11-12', 'https://www.hi.de/ma/artikel/xxx'], ['2019-11-11', 'https://www.hi.de/au/artikel/xxx']]
>>> [[u] + w for u,w in zip(ur, wh)]
[['https://www.hi.de/hu/sitemap.xml', 'No-Date', 'https://www.hi.de/hu/artikel/xxx', ''], ['https://www.hi.de/ma/sitemap.xml', '2019-11-13', 'https://www.hi.de/ma/artikel/xxx'], ['https://www.hi.de/au/sitemap.xml', '2019-11-12', 'https://www.hi.de/ma/artikel/xxx']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `enumerate`.

```
ui = [[x] + wh[i] for i,x in enumerate(ur)]
print(ui)
```

Output:

```
[
    ['https://www.hi.de/hu/sitemap.xml','No-Date','https://www.hi.de/hu/artikel/xxx',''],
    ['https://www.hi.de/ma/sitemap.xml', '2019-11-13','https://www.hi.de/ma/artikel/xxx'],
    ['https://www.hi.de/au/sitemap.xml','2019-11-12','https://www.hi.de/ma/artikel/xxx']
]
```

Comment: `enumerate` is useless there, you're not using `x`, you should use `range` if you just want the index, but simply iterating over our list is best option in this example.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a zip:

[(x[0],x[1][0],x[1][1]) for x in zip(ur, wh)]